# In android:how to make a android application to send the report daily at end of the day or 24 hours once

Tags: android

I have to send report via email every end of the day from my android  application . How can I schedule the task to execute once a day. If internet is unavailable the report send when internet comes back.
Kindly help me..

Thanks advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use AlarmManager to trigger alarm at specific peroid or at different intervals..set up a Broadcast Receiver to get the alarm fired....and start an intent service to send emails in the background

an example class to receive alarm in mainactivity:

```
public void setRepeatingAlarm()
{

     Intent intent = new Intent(this, ReceiveAlarm.class);
      PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
        intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
      am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),
        (10000 * 1000), pendingIntent);
}
```

Broadcast Receiver:

```
public class ReceiveAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {


     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {         
         context.startService(new Intent(context, InService.class));
     }
}
```

Intent service class example:

```
 public class InService extends IntentService
    {
        public InService() {
            super("InService");
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

//send email here
}

}
```

Declare your broadcast receiver / service class in manifest inside   tags

```
<receiver android:name="ReceiveAlarm" />
<service android:name="InService"></service>
```

Answer (score 1):

For the schedule, for sure you must see AlarmManager http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html.

Answer (score 0):

Have you heared of Services in android.

**1.Create a service**

**2.Use Alarm Manager,BroadCastReciever**

for eg,

```
service.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,cal.getTimeInMillis(), REPEAT_TIME, pending);
```

**3.Boot Action when the tablet is switched on**

for eg,

```
Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())
```

Here is the great tutorial http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html This may help you